# Google Maps API v3 'dragend' event fires before maps finishes sliding

Tags: events, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, mouseevent

I have noticed that when you drag the map, if you drag with an accelerating movement, after you release the mouse, the map has some sort of momentum and it keeps sliding for a short period of time, but the 'dragend' event is fired when you release the mouse (which to me it seems correct).

But how can you get the exact moment when the maps finishes SLIDING? I'm not interested in 'center_changed' / 'bounds_changed' solutions, because I need to make a XHR request on the event, and process some data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about the `idle` event, which is fired only once at the end (unlike `center_changed` and `bounds_changed`). From [the docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map):

> This event is fired when the map becomes idle after panning or
>   zooming.

Comment: man I feel dumb. thank you so very much. although it has just a little delay after the sliding stops (maybe half a second), it's perfect for my application. god bless!

Comment: and to add something useful: the 'idle' event is perfect because it's fired even if the drag hasn't ended (i.e. you haven't released the mouse yet, but the panning / mouse movement has stopped)

Answer (score 3):

Try using `idle` event. Link to [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map).

> This event is fired when the map becomes idle after panning or
>   zooming.

If you want **idle event to fire only after dragend** then try the snippet below.

This code prints coordinates to console after both `dragend` and `idle` events fire.

```
mapObj.addListener('dragend', function () {
    var idleListener = mapObj.addListener('idle', function () {
        google.maps.event.removeListener(idleListener);
        console.log(mapObj.getCenter().lat()); 
        console.log(mapObj.getCenter().lng());
    });
});
```